# Problems when trying to join multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge, left-join, missing-data, cbind

I have three data frames: `df1`, `df2`, `df3` with the same number of columns and rows, in the same order.Their column names are exactly the same except for the last three columns (42:43) which are specific to each `df` (e.g.: col41df1, cold42df1, col43df1...col41df2, col42df2, col43df2...col41df3, col42df3, col43df3...).

I wanted to join the three data frames so that the columns that are specific to each would be appended at the end and I would end up with a data frame with 49 columns, rather than 43.I managed that with:

```
df_merged <- df1 %>%
left_join(df2)%>%
left_join(df3)
```

However, something goes wrong during the join because df_merged appears to have 6 NA values while none of the original data frames I joined had any.

Help please?

Thanks!

Comment: *"with the same number of columns and rows, in the same order"* If rows have the same order, why not just bind columns with `cbind`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the rows are in the same order across all 3 dataframes, there's no need to use a join. Instead, simply grab the 3 columns you want from the second and third dataframes and attach them to the first, as such:

```
df_merged <- cbind(df1, df2[, c(41:43)], df3[, c(42:43)])
```

Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), value=c(5,10,25))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), value=c(3,6,9), morevalues=c(4,5,9))

library(dplyr)

merged_df <- data.frame(df1, df2[,c(2:3)])
merged_df
```